# Pass variable to command prompt from python

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I am trying to run a command in python to change the computer name. I want to take the new computer name as user input. I use the below command:

```
WMIC computersystem where name = host_name rename name = new_name
```

In my current code `host_name` and `new_name` are variables to store required data. However when I ran the code it did not work. Is there any suggestions as to how to achieve the task? The code is as follows:

```
import os
host_name = os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME')
new_name = str(input()).upper()
os.system(r'start /wait cmd /c WMIC computersystem where name =' + host_name + 'rename name ='+ new_name)
```

What am i doing wrong? I tried with subprocess as well but that didnt work either.

Comment: I think there should be a _space_ inserted immediately before `rename`...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes I noticed that. Btw I already figured it out( see answer below)  but thanks for the input

Answer (score -1):

After some hit and trial got the code to work using the following line.

```
    os.system('start /wait cmd /c WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM where caption="'+ host_name +'" rename "' + new_name + '"')
```

The quotes have to be explicity supplied as part of the string according to cmd syntax. Also after some googling changed the `where name =` with `where caption =`

Comment: Glad you have a solution. Using subprocess is the more capable way to go.

Comment: @lit i am new to this so if you could help me out with the subprocess syntax will be more than happy to incorporate it in my code

Comment: There are -many- examples of subprocess on the net. Search is your friend.